# Single word (Preferably) for phenomenon when two persons who are at not good terms with each other and involve third person to correspond between them

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, idioms

What is it called (Preferably single word) for phenomenon that is taking place when three parties are involved such that first two persons (Group of people, party or Departments, etc) are at not good terms with each other. And so first party involves you (or your department) as the third person to talk (Converse, correspond) to the second party and vice versa. The question is about what kind of phenomenon is happening between all the three parties and not what the third party party is doing individualistically.

The point of this is to highlight to the management the amount of work that the third party (its department or members of its group) have to undertake is a overburdening our department (third party).

Example:
________ is causing excessive work burnout, disgruntlement, disengagement in our department (within third party) since the XYZ department (first party) is reluctant to correspond with ABC department (Second party) and vice versa. And we (third party) have to pay the price.

Comment: Note that the third person is often called a "go-between".

Comment: The abstract noun follows from the agent noun; mediator --> mediation; arbitrator --> arbitration.

Answer (score 1):

**Mediation** may be the word you are looking for. However, it implies that the third party is trying to end the existing disagreement.

The mere act of coming between is [**intermediation**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intermediation).

Another word that comes to mind is [**intervention**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intervention). Check out the meaning of *[intervene](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intervene)*. If you opt for this word, make sure the context is clear, as the word has a few meanings.

Personally, I think ***intermediation*** works best here. If someone intermediates, they act as an intermediary (a person who passes messages or proposals between two people or groups).

Answer (score 0):

In British English, we use *mediation*

> mediation = the process of talking to two separate people or groups involved in a disagreement to try to help them to agree or find a solution to their problems:
>
> "Last-minute attempts at mediation failed."
>
> "In divorce cases where there are children, mediation is preferable to going to court."
>
> [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mediation)

In America, we have:

> mediation: the act or process of mediating: such as
>
> a: intervention between conflicting parties to promote reconciliation, settlement, or compromise
>
> "The town feud raged until April … when, with the mediation of William N. Byers the dispute was settled and the name of Denver selected for the settlement."
>
> b: specifically : a means of resolving disputes outside of the judicial system by voluntary participation in negotiations structured by agreement of the parties and usually conducted under the guidance and supervision of a trained intermediary
>
> "More couples are considering mediation—or using a mediator to help them reach a compromise—rather than hiring two lawyers who fight it out for their clients."
>
> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mediation)

In your context, the word is preferable to the much less frequently used financial term:

> *intermediation* BANKING, FINANCE =
> the process by which money that has been invested in a bank, etc. is lent to people, companies, etc. who want to borrow it:
>
> [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mediation)

Comparison on google ngram shows *mediation* to have been in widespread use for many decades in areas such as law, communities, relationships and psychology. *intermediation* is a more recent term that is used ten time less and almost exclusively in financial contexts.

Answer (score 0):

*From the Shorter Oxford English Dictionary*

> **intercession** The action of interceding or pleading on behalf of another, esp. by prayer; a prayer on behalf of another; in *pl.*, the part of a church service at which such prayers are said. Late Middle English

- Intercession is causing excessive work burnout, disgruntlement, disengagement …

Answer (score 0):

Second source 1:
[Triangulation / Backchanneling](https://www.bates-communications.com/bates-blog/overcoming-triangulation-how-to-stop-that-toxic-backchanneling)

> What is Triangulation?

> We’ve all experienced this at some point: Instead of directly expressing an opposing view or objection to something you said or did, someone has gone to a third party to complain about you.  Not only is this infuriating, it can create toxic dynamics in a team by rewarding passive-aggressive behavior. It also can be quite awkward when someone comes to you to complain about someone else when you know they have not discussed their concerns with the other person.

> This phenomenon is often called triangulation because the “complainer” has gone to a third party and not directly to the “object” or “victim” of their concern.  It is a passive-aggressive behavior because the complainer never deals directly with you and tries to indirectly undermine you.

Second source 2: [Triangulation at workplace](https://rapidlearninginstitute.com/blog/triangulation-at-work/)

> But in the lexicon of workplace psychology, triangulation is another thing altogether — and a bad one. This kind of triangulation happens when one employee takes an issue or conflict with a co-worker to a third co-worker.